# Standards for smart homes and things

Tags: google-smart-home

What are the standards or protocols for communicating smart home elements? If I release my smart light bulb, what standards should I follow in order for it to work with Google Home, Xiaomi Mi Home, Amazon Alexa, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate [with the Google Assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview), you will need a way for the lightbulb communicate through the Internet. This could be through a direct Wi-Fi service or an Internet connected hub. [Execution](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local) can be done over a local network, but still requires access to the Internet to respond to other intents.

I do not know the requirements of the other systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are some news reports about the international smart home standard from The Open Connectivity Foundation ([OCF](https://openconnectivity.org/)).

https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2020/01/06/smart-home-standard/